# Fetch posts by there location from firebase with swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to fetch posts from my firebase database and print them to the console when the user enters a 1km radius of the posts. I can find hardly anything about doing this online. Could someone help me out with the code to do this.

[image: Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GeoFire for JavaScript](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js)

> GeoFire is an open-source library that allows you to store and query a
>   set of keys based on their geographic location. At its heart, GeoFire
>   simply stores locations with string keys. Its main benefit, however,
>   is the possibility of retrieving only those keys within a given
>   geographic area - all in realtime.
>
> GeoFire uses the Firebase Realtime Database for data storage, allowing
>   query results to be updated in realtime as they change. GeoFire
>   selectively loads only the data near certain locations, keeping your
>   applications light and responsive, even with extremely large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily find places within 1 km by this.

```
var array = [Any]()
handle = ref?.child("Location").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
       for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        let value = snap.value

        // Using value["latitude"] & value["longitude"] find distance from location

       if distance <= 1.0 { 
            array.append(value)
       }
       print(array)
     }
    })
```